# Multiple tables in one Laravel model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm programming a 'module permission management' system that is multi-language capable.  I'm using three related tables:

modules, modules_trans, modules_permissions

Is it acceptable (best practice) to use a single model to handle all three related tables in Laravel?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, your relationships can be as follows

```
class Language
{
  public function modules()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Module');
  }
}

class Permission
{
  public function modules()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Module');
  }
}

class Module
{
  public function languages()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Language');
  }
  public function permissions()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission');
  }
}
```

Your Database should follow the **ACID** ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)) as much as possible! So.... **No!** don't mix up things. Not atleast if your relationships are as specified above.

Therefore, your tables must be as follows...

```
module
id | name | ....

language_module
id | language_id | module_id

module_permission
id | module_id | permission_id
```